# Output is not execute correctly

Tags: python-3.x

Python Program for Sum of squares of first n natural numbers:

```
def sum(n):
    sm = 0
    for i in range(n + 1):

        sm += i ** 2
        return sm
n = 4
print(sum(n))
```

if I try to execute this program even when I type as same as in the site it executes "0". but if I copy paste the same code from that site the execution is working properly and executed as "30".
WWWHHHYYY?

Comment: Your return statement is indented too far, so it returns during the first iteration of the for-loop.  Unindent it to the same level as the for-loop and it should calculate correctly. Another improvement would be to change `range(n + 1)` to `range(1, n + 1)` so you don't iterate over the zero. It doesn't impact the result, but if you were calculating the product it would.

Comment: You shouldnt define a custom function with the same name as a built-in one

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving sum as 0 because your return statement has incorrect indentation. After changing the indentation on line 5, it is working fine.

```
def sum(n):
    sm = 0
    for i in range(n + 1):
        sm += i ** 2
    return sm
n = 4
print(sum(n))
```